# Trying to do MySQL Concat

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this below data

```
ID     name         page1     page2      page3     page4     page5
1      demo           1         1          1         1         1
10     compliance     1         1          0         0         0
12     compliance     1         1          1         0         0
20     compliance     0         1          0         1         0
25     compliance     1         1          0         0         1
```

I am trying to combine the columns which has 1 into it.

I tried it by **Concat** like below

```
Select id, name,
Concat (
case when page1 = 1 then 'page1, ' End
case when page2 = 1 then 'page2, ' End
case when page3 = 1 then 'page3, ' End
case when page4 = 1 then 'page4, ' End
case when page5 = 1 then 'page5, ' End
)
```

But this gives me below

```
ID     name          yes page
1      demo         page1, page2, page3, page4, page5
10     compliance    NULL
12     compliance    NULL
20     compliance    NULL
25     compliance    NULL
```

and I am looking to have something like below

```
ID     name          yes page
1      demo         page1, page2, page3, page4, page5,
10     compliance   page1, page2,
12     compliance   page1, page2, page3,
20     compliance   page2, page3, page4,
25     compliance   page1, page2, page5,
```

Please let me know if there is I can do to my concat statement to work, so I can have table like above. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a `CASE` expression where nothing matches, the result of the expression is `NULL`. When you concatenate `NULL` with any other string, the result is `NULL`. This explains the result you're seeing.

The solution is including a default value with each expression:

```
case when page1 = 1 then 'page1, ' Else '' End
```

Remember, `NULL` does not mean "empty". It means "I don't know". When you combine **anything** with "I don't know", the result is *always* going to be "I don't know".

Answer (score 0):

In MySql, *concat* honours NULL values and any string being concatenated with NULL results in NULL.

Instead, use `concat_ws` which ignores NULL values. Ie,

```
Concat_ws (', '
  case when page1 = 1 then 'page1' End,
  case when page2 = 1 then 'page2' End...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for [CONCAT_WS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) and IF(condition, 'text', NULL).  [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rBtSZVxhLGAg8HuvxrDo23/0).

```sql
SELECT ID, name,
       CONCAT_WS(', ',
         IF(page1, 'page1', NULL),
         IF(page2, 'page2', NULL),
         IF(page3, 'page3', NULL),
         IF(page4, 'page4', NULL),
         IF(page5, 'page5', NULL)) pages
  FROM tbl;
```

CONCAT_WS() takes a list of items and concatenates them ignoring the ones with NULL values. And, it puts in a separator (comma - space) in my example.